# Dynamically redirect to another view in to div in main view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to load view in to div in main view. This is my main view

```
<html>
 <head>
  //some contents
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="contents" id="subContents" ng-controller="distributeViewsController" ng-view>
      //other view loaded hear
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is my Index view

```
<html>
 <body>
  //contents
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm using angular routing to route index view in to main view. This is my js

```
$routeProvider
 .when('/Index', {
   templateUrl: 'EZ_Main/Index',
   controller: 'distributeViewsController'
 })
```

Routing is work fine with `<a href="#Index">Index</a>` but now i want to load index view dynamically. Let say i have two views called Index and Home. I need to call my main view first and after that load **Index** or **Home** according to the request(the request need to say load the main view and after go to Index or Home view).Can anyone tell me how can i do this if this method was possible or another way to do that.

Comment: I think you should consider [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). ***************** I need to call my main view first and after that load Index or Home according to the request************ It will provide you this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

$routeProvider.when('/main/:page', {templateUrl: 'views/main.html', controller: 'main.MainViewCtrl'});

Answer (score 0):

```
    angularApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider','$httpProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider,$httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/Index', {templateUrl: 'EZ_Main/Index',
   controller: 'distributeViewsController'
 });
    $routeProvider.when('/main/:page', {templateUrl: 'views/main.html', controller: 'main.MainViewCtrl'});

       // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
        }
        //disable IE ajax request caching
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
       // $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    }]);
```

Comment: If URL changed then rout provider call